# Why does virtual terminal throw error on eval while Gnome Terminal works?

Tags: 18.04, bash, virtual-console

I sometimes use the virtual terminal on my Ubuntu (18.04.5) laptop and commands return error.
For example I do:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
2. login on my account

```
bob@mylaptop:$ ls
file1 file2 file3
-bash: eval: line 2: premature end of file (EOF) when looking for matching "'"
-bash: eval: line 3: syntax error: premature end of file
```

(*sorry, errors are in French so it's a personal translation*)

I understand that there is a missing quote in the `eval` code, but I don't know how to fix it. Other commands return same anomaly

Commands still return expected results, and I don't find any missing quote in `~/.bashrc`. My normal terminal (Gnome Terminal)  is working just fine.

### Edit :

I found this file that call `eval` and don't do anything. This file is called by `/etc/profile`

```
$ cat 01-locale-fix.sh 
# Make sure the locale variables are set to valid values.
eval $(/usr/bin/locale-check C.UTF-8)
```

```
$ cat /etc/profile
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Here is $PS1

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]Bob@Laptop\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

Tracing with `set -x` link this with opam, which is something is used. There is a long sentence where `'can'\''t'` is present and I think this is wrong.

```
$
++ _opam_env_hook
++ local previous_exit_status=0
+++ opam env --shell=bash --readonly
++ the long sentence with 'can'\''t' in it.
```

Comment: Does the error message really start with `bash:`, or is it `-bash:`? A virtual terminal should start a *login shell* whereas a gnome-terminal runs a non-login interactive shell by default - which may explain the difference in behavior

Comment: It begin with `-bash:` but yes I checked `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_login` files. Also running `bash -x` skip the error

Comment: Based on the error message, I'd look for a *file named* `eval` that is sourced from one of the startup files (including `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d`) - rather than an `eval` *command*

Comment: I found the `/etc/bash.bashrc` with something I think is strange...There is not `eval` file sourced. The precedent file is sourced in `/etc/profile` @steeldriver

Comment: @Gowachin That line is fine. It's part of the heredoc in `cat <<-EOF; ...; EOF`, which just prints the message.

Comment: I edited and found the `eval` call but I don't understand the line. I think it depend of $PS1...

Comment: Run `set -x` to get a trace of what's happening behind the scenes. You can use `set +x` to turn it off afterward.

Comment: Edit is done, it's linked with opam. I'll investigate this !

Comment: Thanks all, it was a ghost error message from opam...I don't understand how it is faulty but I upgraded the version as requested and I don't have any error left. The trace was a great help, thanks a lot to @GordonDavisson !